How do I make the car tire rotate as the car moves?
I’m working on a racing game but this issue has me really stuck.
The code below is supposed to make the wheel spin based on the velocity and also rotate side to side based on the steering angle.
The wheel spin and the wheel steering work as intended but the problem is, the wheel seems to have its z axis flipped every 360 degree rotation in the x axis.
I don’t understand why this is the case.
private void Update()
    {
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.x, steerAngle, transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.z);

        wheelxRotation = Vector3.Dot(rb.GetPointVelocity(wheelMesh.transform.position), transform.forward) * Time.deltaTime / wheelCircumference * 360;
        Quaternion steerRotation = Quaternion.Euler(wheelMesh.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.x, steerAngle, wheelMesh.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.z);
        wheelMesh.transform.localRotation = steerRotation;
        wheelMesh.transform.Rotate(-Vector3.right, wheelxRotation);

        Debug.Log(wheelMesh.transform.localEulerAngles);
    }

Below are the images of the car and the local euler angles of the wheel at that point.
As you can see, the wheel seems to have flipped despite not changing the local z axis.
This flip occurs every 360 degree rotation of the wheel (as it spins).


I believe that Unity had a tutorial with a car that includes a wheel rotation.

You might be interested in WheelCollider or directly Go with Vehicle Physics Pro (free)

I have actually found the solution to this problem, but it's a very workaround method.
public class Wheel : MonoBehaviour
{
    ....
    public GameObject wheelMesh;
    public GameObject carModel;

    private Rigidbody rb;
    private CarController carController;

    ...

    private float wheelCircumference;
    private float wheelxRotation; // in degrees
    private float lastyRotation;

    void Start()
    {
        ...

        defaultWheelMeshPosition = new Vector3(wheelMesh.transform.localPosition.x, -restlength+wheelDiameter/2+wheelOffset, wheelMesh.transform.localPosition.z);

        wheelCircumference = 2*Mathf.PI*(wheelDiameter/2);
        lastyRotation = transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.y;
        wheelMesh.transform.Rotate(carModel.transform.up, lastyRotation, Space.World);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.x, steerAngle, transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.z);

        wheelxRotation = Vector3.Dot(rb.GetPointVelocity(wheelMesh.transform.position), transform.forward) * Time.deltaTime / wheelCircumference * 360;
        float yRotationDifference = transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.y - lastyRotation;
        wheelMesh.transform.Rotate(Vector3.right,-wheelxRotation);
        wheelMesh.transform.Rotate(carModel.transform.up, yRotationDifference,Space.World);
        lastyRotation += yRotationDifference;
        Debug.Log(yRotationDifference);
    }

I think the problem was that the two rotations were conflicting each other as rotating one axis changes the direction of the other axes as well, so the rotation wasn't as simple as changing the y value. As I was just setting the y axis rotation directly, this prevented the rotate method from properly working as some of its values kept being reset.
I solved this by simply rotating the wheel (for steering) around the transform.up of another object for reference so that the axis does not change. This required me to have some extra variables to find the angle difference.
I don't know if there is another way to do this, where perhaps you can set the rotation angle around an axis directly and equate it to the steer angle instead of manually calculating the angle difference each frame, but this works for me.

Maybe it has something to do with the usage of euler angles, as described here : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html
The rotations are stored as Quaternions
You are affecting the whole rotation of the object, but if you just wanna rotate around the x and/or the y axis, juste call the Rotate() method, and then specify the axis and value, as manipulating quaternions can be tricky.

Maybe it will solve your problem, if not then i don't know what is happening here. Let me know
